# My nvidia-settings /etc/X11/xorg.conf seems to not be saving or running?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I've got a fresh install of Arch-Linux, I'm running Gnome/GDM/Nvidia proprietary driver from `pacman -S nvidia`

I then went
`sudo nvidia-xconfig` and `sudo nvidia-settings` changed my monitor to 1920x1080, 120Hz refresh rate, but when I restart my computer it's only on 60Hz and I can't figure out why, there is no errors in the console when I hit save or anything to the config, this is the config now:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"

EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ XL2420T"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 140.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 120.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 660 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_120 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Any help would be great, this is extremely annoying to have to change my settings every time I reboot, thanks!

Comment: Are you making the changes manually, or through the proprietary Nvidia Driver Settings binary?

Answer (score 0):

`nvidia-settings` saves its settings in `$HOME/.nvidia-settings-rc`. So, if you run it with `sudo`, it will save your changes in `/root/.nvidia-settings-rc` so you won't see them after a reboot.

Either edit your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` manually or run `nvidia-settings` as your normal user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that GDM ignores Xorg configuration settings.
Refer https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=38041